# how to reference a com exe from unmanaged c++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, com

I am not very familiar with unmanaged c++, as I've only worked with MFC and Dot Net.  I have an unmanaged dll that I would like to reference an out of process server.  I've tried the following:

```
#import "C:\Program Files (x86)\statconn\DCOM\bin\StatConnectorSrv.exe"
using namespace STATCONNECTORSRVLib;
```

and

```
#import "C:\Program Files (x86)\statconn\DCOM\bin\StatConnectorSrv.tlb"
using namespace STATCONNECTORSRVLib;
```

STATCONNECTORSRVLib contains the object StatConnector.  However when I try to instantiate StatConnector, I get an "incomplete type is not allowed", and intellisense tells me StatConnector is a struct.

```
StatConnector *conn = new StatConnector();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say your StatConnectorSrv.tlb contains an interface `ISomething` with a `MyMethod` method, and a coclass `Something`, then you would instantiate it like this:

```
#import "C:\Program Files (x86)\statconn\DCOM\bin\StatConnectorSrv.tlb"
using namespace STATCONNECTORSRVLib;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    CoInitialize(NULL);

    ISomethingPtr ptr(__uuidof(Something)); // create an instance of the Something coclass and get an ISomething pointer back
    ptr->MyMethod(parameters of the method);

    CoUninitialize();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ok, so I noticed that when I add the type library in .Net it also references StatConnLib, which contains the interface so I am also importing StatConnLib.tlb.  However, `IStatConnector ptr(__uuidof(StatConnector));` gives me several errors: _object of abstract class type "StatConnectorCommonLib::IStatConnector" is not allowed_, _no instance of "StatConnectorCommonLib::IStatConnector::IStatConnector" matches the argument list. argument types are: (const _GUID).  Another poster was able to use `StatConnector *conn = new StatConnector();` from unmanaged c++ so maybe a problem with #import?

Comment: Are you sure you typed IStatConnectorPtr and not IStatConnector? You must declare something like `IStatConnectorPtr ptr(__uuidof(StatConnector))`. Ptr is a special postfix.

Comment: Ahh, yes, missed that.  Now it works, thank you.  Why does IStatConnectionPtr not show in the object browser?  Is it generated by the import process?

Comment: @JustinLilly - Absolutely, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16380580/com-c-how-to-use-c-to-call-com/16382024#16382024