# Access violation during execution on CreateInstance function

Tags: c++, com, smart-pointers, ocx, createinstance

I'm setting a program to create a COM connection from an ocx file.

I'm using visual studio 2019 with debug x86. It correctly generate the .tlh and .tli files.

My failed tests:

- Use visualtudio 2017 and 2019
- Use `CoCreateInstance`:

  ```
  IMachine* machine = NULL;

  // this gives the same error:
  HRESULT hr2 = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_Machine, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, 
                                 IID_IMachine,
                                 reinterpret_cast<LPVOID*>(&machine));
  ```
- Replace `CLSID_Machine` by the `_uuidof(IMachine)`
- Replace `CLSID_Machine` by the `LPCWSTR clsidString`

This is a part of my code:

```
#import "lib.ocx" no_namespace , named_guids

HRESULT hr1 = CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED);
try {
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr1))
    {
      IMachinePtr machineCUPtr;
      HRESULT hr2 = machineCUPtr.CreateInstance(CLSID_Machine, NULL, 
                                                CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER); //Failure

       if (FAILED(hr2))
        {
              std::cout << "Fail:" << hr2 << std::endl;
            }
            else {
              std::cout << "Success: " << hr2 << std::endl;
            }
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "Fail CoInit: " << std::endl;
        }
    }
    catch (_com_error& e)
    {
        std::cout << "COM ERROR catched " << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Code = %08lx\n" << e.Error() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Meaning = %s\n" << e.ErrorMessage() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Source = %s\n" << (LPCSTR)e.Source() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Description = %s\n" << (LPCSTR)e.Description() << std::endl;

    }
    CoUninitialize();
}
```

I still have this error:

> Exception raised to 0x00B20768 in myApp.exe : 0xC000000005 : Access
>   violation during execution at location 0x00B20768.

**Edit:**

```
'''

    #include <iostream>
    #import "libcom.ocx"

    using namespace LIBCOM;

    int main()
    {
        CoInitialize(NULL);

        IMachinePtr machineCUPtr(__uuidof(Machine)); //Same error
        machineCUPtr->MyMethod(parameters of the method);

        CoUninitialize();

        return 0;
    }

''''
```

Comment: Your code is incorrect. If you're using #import (and interface smart wrappers like IBlablaPtr), it should be similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/16367624/403671

Comment: Thank you for your reply but it dosen't work, this gives the same error. Instanciate like your example call the CreateInstance function.

Comment: Of course it works, you're probably missing something. Post your code.

Comment: I have added my code in my post.

Comment: Here is the most simple example I could come up with: https://pastebin.com/raw/YrTqgAiQ try this. If it displays 0 then your client code is ok, but your target COM server "libcom.ocx" is broken somehow.

Comment: It's works with the example! So the problem is occured by my ocx file...