# How do I access static members of a c# library from c++ code?

Tags: c#, c++, com, interop

I have been given a library written in C# and I need to use it in a C++ project.  The C# library has been exported to a .tlb type library, which I can successfully import into my C++ project by using the #import directive.

Being utterly unfamiliar with COM I can't for the life of me figure out how to get at static member functions on any classes.  Here's how I access it in C#:

```
void Function()
{
    StaticClass.StaticMethod();
}
```

And then you get into the C++ side, what gets generated in the .tlh file is:

```
struct __declspec(uuid("some big long thing")) 
/* dual interface */_StaticClass;
//long while later
_COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF(_StaticClass, __uuidof(_StaticClass));
```

So I'm trying to figure out how to get use of the static class and haven't had any luck with Google.  The only example anywhere else in any other project I have access to gives me something similar to this:

```
_StaticClassPtr s = _StaticClassPtr(__uuidof(_StaticClass));
```

but the example I have isn't for a static class anyway.

Basically I'm stuck with nowhere to even really start.  This fails with "Unhandled exception at  in <executable>: Microsoft C++ exception: _com_error at memory location <location>"

---

Edit:  Since @dxiv informed me static methods aren't usable with COM interop, there's another option marked 'obsolete' that does not use static members -- problem is I get exactly the same exception when I construct the instance with similar syntax:

```
IInstanceClassPtr p = _IInstanceClassPtr(__uuidof(_InstanceClass));
```

The same exception is thrown, "_com_error at memory location"

Comment: Type libraries describe COM interfaces, and COM does not support static methods. Either define a non-static method in the interface, or use a mechanism other than COM for interop.

Comment: The answer is yes you can if the c++ is managed code.  It has been a long time since I've attempted to do this.  You have to understand how the Microsoft Linker works.   There are different memory spaces where the linker put variables.  There is a public area where static varibable are located and in c++ and you have to reference the public memory area instead of the default memory area.  Microsoft does not advertise this very well and it may not be possible to do inside VS.  But you can using the command line compiler get access to all linker objects.

Comment: Your edit is far from clear. #import works fine for C/C++ to use .NET COM object (but no static, that will never work). see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/16367624/403671 @paulsm4 - "COM is an obsolete technology" is very very wrong. COM is used everywhere in Windows, WinRT is COM based, etc. C++/CLI is actually an obsolete technology.

Answer (score -1):

Reading your question you would like to use C# using COM Interop. What I done is something like this. Starting from the assumption that COM is the acronym of Component Object Model and to use it you need an instantiable, local or remote, object. The example below creates an "in-proc" instance of the CLR object.

Create an interface which is exposed to COM:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Provides an entry point for COM clients.
    /// </summary>
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [Guid("A9E6D7FE-34FD-4A6B-9EB2-DC91F4AE567B")]
    public interface IMyAccessor
    {
         void ExecuteStaticMethod();
         // add anything else like methods, property,
    }
}
```

then implement the interface in a C# class:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The implementation of IMyAccessor.
    /// </summary>
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [Guid("C65A7F81-641C-4F17-B34A-DEB88B4158E8")]
    [ProgId("MyCompany.MyAccessor")]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    [ComDefaultInterface(typeof(IMyAccessor))]
    public sealed class MyAccessor: IMyAccessor
    {
        public void ExecuteStaticMethod() { StaticClass.StaticMethod(); }
    }
}
```

export the TLB and import it in C++ project (MyAccessor is only a name I used here) in the header file of your C++ class using the following clause:

`#import "MyAccessor.tlb"`

Within the class header add a line like the following:

```
MyNamespace::IMyAccessorPtr m_IMyAccessor;
```

And in the class implementation use the following:

```
        HRESULT hr = m_IMyAccessor.CreateInstance(__uuidof(MyNamespace::MyAccessor));
        if (FAILED(hr))
        {
            // do something if failed
        }

        m_IMyAccessor->ExecuteStaticMethod(); // this will execute your static method in C#
```

**NOTE**: when exporting the TLB use the correct switchs. In an x64 environment (/win64) must be used to have the right pointer size: normally tlbexp returns pointer usable in a 32bit environment. This is important if you want to extend the class with more sofistcated methods.

**NOTE 2**: if the returned HRESULT from `CreateInstance` is something like "class not registered", remember to execute the registration of the TLB wih REGTLIB.